# How to control loading in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

When i try to run my scripts and call this method, when i enter URL into address bar, loading starts and loading take much time, 
but sometime when refresh page page proper loaded on the spot so please help me out.
How can i handle this issue in automation.

```
public static MainPage LaunchBrowserAndLogin(String currentScriptName, String LoginUser) throws Throwable {
            try {
                  killprocess();
                  LaunchBrowser();
                  String siteUrl = null;
                  if (excelSiteURL != null) {
                        if (excelSiteURL.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                              siteUrl = CONFIG.getProperty("siteName");
                        }else{
                              if (excelSiteURL.contains("SiteName")) {
                                    siteUrl=excelSiteURL;
                              }
                        }
                  } else {
                        siteUrl = CONFIG.getProperty("SiteName");
                  }
                  driver.get("https://QA.YYYY.com/ABC9/#/login"); 
                  System.out.println("URL for Login: "+siteUrl);
                  CheckErrorPageNotFound();
                  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Long.parseLong(CONFIG.getProperty("pageLoadTime")), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  enterUserID(currentScriptName, LoginUser);
                  enterPasswd(currentScriptName);
                  MandatoryFieldSkipErrMsg("~~~~~~ Mandatory Field is skipped, Getting Error: ");
                  ClickLoginButton();
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }catch(){
                DesireScreenshot("AfterClickOnLoginButton");
                String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(t);
                String errorMsg = t.getMessage();
                errorMsg = "\n\n\n\n Login failed.See screenshot 'LoginFailed' \n\n\n\n" + errorMsg + stackTrace;
                Exception c = new Exception(errorMsg);
                ErrorUtil.addVerificationFailure(c);
                killprocess();
                IsBrowserPresentAlready = false;
                throw new Exception(errorMsg);
            }
         return new MainPage(driver);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the details of the selenium and driver versions that you are using.

Comment: Selenium webdriver, 3.1.10 , and chrome version 81

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether page is fully loaded or not in that case we will use the below code.

> > new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));

Then as per your question I believe that some web elements are not properly getting loaded. So what you can do add one more explicit wait and put that wait inside try catch block as shown below.

> > try
> >             {
> >                 new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Abhishek")));
> >                 System.out.println("Completed");
> >             }
> >             catch( TimeoutException e)
> >             {
> >                 System.out.println("Reloading");
> >                 driver.navigate().refresh();
> >             }

If it is unable to find that element then in the catch block it will refresh the page and in this way you can proceed further.

Note: I could have written the script for you but application url is invalid.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504